# What happens when the limits of DocuSign string fields are exceeded?

Tags: docusignapi

The DocuSign SOAP API lists various limits on API fields, e.g. Username can be a maximum of 100 chars, Email can be a maximum of 100 chars.  Does this mean that together, the "friendly name" and the email address can be 200 chars?

For Example, would this be okay (i.e. only an email):
ThisIsAReallyLongUserNameWhichWillBeAbout58CharactersLong@gmail.com ?

And this would NOT be okay:
ThisIsAReallyLongUserNameWhichWillBeAbout58CharactersLong [ThisIsAReallyLongUserNameWhichWillBeAbout58CharactersLong@gmail.com] ?

And what happens if those (or other) string limits are exceeded?  Is an error thrown or is it just truncated?  If an error, what kind of error?

Comment: Have you tried out the interactive docs? http://iodocs.docusign.com/?version=v2. I don't know the answer but I'm going to guess it sends back a 400.

Comment: iodocs is in REST, which has different requirements. I'm not sure of the answer for this off the top of my head, but if you did a sample SOAP call to Demo you would find the answer pretty easily.

Comment: Could you just try it and see what happens? (You should be able to answer and accept your own answer)

Answer (score 0):

Using the Visual Studio debugger, I modified input fields, and checked the results of the fields in the Envelope which are the the most important to our application (which uses the SOAP API):

- Document Name: This gets truncated to 100 characters by the DocuSign System. No error is generated.
- Recipients -> UserName: if this is greater than 100 characters, the DocuSign SOAP API throws an "Unspecified Error"
- Recipients -> Email: This would be truncated to 100 characters by the DocuSign System ... and therefore the above sample would become something like this "ThisIsAReallyLongUserNameWhichWillBeAbout58CharactersLong [ThisIsAReallyLongUserNameWhichWillBeAbou".  No error was generated, but it would fail if used as an email address.
- Email Subject:  This gets truncated to 100 characters by the DocuSign System. No error is generated.